# FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged not showing my logged in state

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am following a Flutter/Firebase tutorial and am having a problem with the Firebase authentication.

My understanding of the code is that the listener will redirect the user to the appropriate page depending upon the user login status. Fro the code this appears to be determined by the status of "snapshot.hasData" however when I run my code I am always directed to the FeedScreen.

I have added a couple of debugging print statements and their output is shown below. I cannot be logged in as I have no user records in Firebase.

```
Restarted application in 1,971ms.
I/flutter ( 6215): false
I/flutter ( 6215): ConnectionState.waiting
I/flutter ( 6215): true
I/flutter ( 6215): ConnectionState.active
```

The code is as shown below:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget _getScreenId() {
    return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.hasData);
        print(snapshot.connectionState);
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return FeedScreen();
        } else {
          return LoginScreen();
        }
      }
     );
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Learning Flutter',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: _getScreenId(),
      routes: {
        LoginScreen.id: (context) => LoginScreen(),
        SignupScreen.id: (context) => SignupScreen(),
        FeedScreen.id: (context) => FeedScreen(),
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using navigator to change screen between LoginScreen and signupScreen ? when you do login from login screen is it working or not? when you do signup from signup screen is it working or not?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to access either the login or signup screens as when I run the app it immediately goes to the FeedScreen. In my login screen I use the code "onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, SignupScreen.id)". This worked before I added the "_getScreenId()" widget.

Comment: you are navigating to feedscreen because you are login in firebase, logout in feed screen and check what happens. in addition to that if you navigate using navigator streambuilder will not change widget anymore because it dismiss stream.

Comment: I added a button on FeedScreen and was able to logout and it now works. How could I have been logged in when I have no user in Firebase Auth?

Comment: so you want to sign up and when user sign up you want to go feed screen again ?